# GCC, линковка с динамической библиотекой

Tags: c++, linux, c

Я пользуюсь linux. В папке с main.cpp у меня лежат inc_Abc.h и libAbc.so. Всё это я собираю командой:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -L. -lAbc
```

Потом запускаю ./main, но появляется ошибка:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libAbc.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Почему main не видит libAbc.so, который находится в той же папке?

Я знаю, что этот вопрос можно решить, сделав папку с main -- папкой поиска *.so файлов, с помощью ldconfig. Нельзя ли как-то по-другому это решить?

Comment: какова реакция на такой вызов? `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, работает.

Comment: Почитайте про [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

для разработки или тестирования вполне подойдёт использование [переменной окружения LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN80). она может содержать разделённые двоеточием пути для поиска библиотек. текущий каталог, как и обычно, можно обозначить точкой <kbd>.</kbd>.

можно передавать переменную непосредственно при вызове программы:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
```

или экспортировать в текущем экземпляре оболочки:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

тогда в этом экземпляре оболочки можно запускать вашу программу и так:

```
$ ./main
```