# Линковка своих динамических библиотек к исполняемому файлу

Tags: unix, cmake, makefile

Пишу Makefile для проекта, который использует стороннюю динамическую библиотеку. Библиотека лежит в определённой директории, не входящей в список дефолтных.

Компиляция проходит успешно. Проблемы, очевидно, с запуском - не может найти библиотеку.

Можно ли составить Makefile так, чтобы он выполнял функцию, аналогичную функции link_directories в CMake? То есть, чтобы в исполняемый файл был как бы "зашит" путь до библиотеки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно `man ld` нужно сообщить линкеру параметр `-rpath=тот_самый_путь` к библиотекам, который нужно зашить в бинарник. Сделать это можно двумя способами. Через опцию gcc `-Xlinker -rpath=тот_самый_путь`. Если вы используете правила сборки make по-умолчанию, для этих опций подходит переменная `LDFLAGS` в Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS+= -Xlinker -rpath=тот_самый_путь
```

Второй способ -- минуя `gcc` через переменную окружения `LD_RUN_PATH` которую `ld` читает сам в случае, если опции -rpath не было. В Makefile для этого можно написать:

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=тот_самый_путь
```

Или написать `LD_RUN_PATH=тот_самый_путь` перед `$(CC)` непосредственно в правиле для линковки.

В пути может присутствовать подстрока `$ORIGIN`, вместо которой будет подставлен путь к каталогу, содержащему исполняемый файл. См. [`man ld-linux.so`](http://ru.manpages.org/ld-linuxso/8). Пример строки в Makefile:

```
myprogram: LDFLAGS+= -Xlinker -rpath='$$ORIGIN/'
myprogram: myprogram.o
```

Comment: Благодарю! Буду пробовать!

Comment: Всё отлично работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

к программе *make* (и, тем более, *cmake*) как таковой вопрос отношения, насколько я понимаю, не имеет.

ведь [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) — это указание **сборщику**, который запускается на этапе компиляции.

вы же хотите дать указания **загрузчику**. но системный загрузчик во время загрузки (т.е., даже **до** выполнения программы) разыскивает библиотеки по именам, указанным в исполняемом файле, в тех каталогах, в которых он (загрузчик) сконфигурирован их искать. переконфигурировать системынй загрузчик можно с помощью прогрммы *ldconfig* (см. `man ldconfig`).

без переконфигурации же загрузчика вы можете дать такое указание с помощью переменной окружения, например, запуская не программу непосредственно, а скрипт на любом удобном вам языке программирования (например, на языке оболочки), в котором вызывать вашу программу, указав [с помощью переменной окружения `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` путь (пути) к вашей библиотеке (библиотекам)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498204/178576):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=путь программа
```

---

> чтобы в исполняемый файл был как бы "зашит" путь до библиотеки

динамически загрузить во время выполнения библиотеку (указав относительный или полный путь к ней) можно с помощью функции [`dlopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html).

Comment: Да, этот метод я знаю, спасибо. Но интересует именно возможность написания команды-аналога CMake-овского link_directories.

Comment: Я подозревал, что так оно и есть. Но всё же CMake, которая генерирует Makefile, генерирует его так, что дальнейшая сборка программы утилитой Make приводит к созданию исполняемого файла, в котором уже "вшиты" пути к библиотекам. Разве не в Makefile-е это должно быть как-то прописано?

Comment: Понял. Но всё же CMake как-то с этим справляется... Как-то эти пути всё-таки указываются именно в исполняемом файле. Спасибо за dlopen, но это тоже не то. Я не идеален в формулировании вопросов, но всё же надеюсь, что Вы понимаете, что я хочу получить.

Comment: Да, спасибо, в этом Вы правы, это аналог флага -L компилятора. Но суть вопроса в другом, и Вы скорее всего это понимаете)

Comment: перенёс содержимое своих комментариев в текст ответа. надеюсь, так «общая картина» станет вам «виднее».

Comment: Окей. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @AccumPlus, гуглите RPATH, cmake именно им и пользуется. Но это уродское решение, мягко говоря.