# Зависимости Linux

Tags: linux, unix, зависимости

Есть одно приложение, для которого нужна установка зависимостей. Собрал все нужные зависимости в одну папку рядом с приложением. Как сделать так, чтобы недостающее оно вытягивало именно с этой папки, а не с /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu?

Comment: *export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...*

Comment: ключевые слова: "rpath origin". [на этом сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561568/178576). [в интернетах](https://www.google.ru/search?q=rpath+origin). ну или `man ld.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Первый способ.*

Для того, чтобы добавить нашу директорию с библиотеками в список известных директорий надо добавить путь в файл /etc/ld.so.conf  После изменения конфигурационного файла ld.so.conf необходимо, чтобы система перечитала настройки заново. Это делает команда ldconfig  Описанный метод влияет на всю систему в целом и требует доступа администратора системы (root).

---

*Второй способ.*

Использование специальной переменной среды LD_LIBRARY_PATH, в которой перечисляются все каталоги содержащие пользовательские динамические библиотеки.
Для начала посмотрите есть ли у вас такая переменная среды:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Если в ответ выводится пустая строка, значит такой переменной среды нет.
Устанавливается она следующим образом:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/вашпуть
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Eсли у Вас в системе эта переменная среды уже уставновлена, нужно новый каталог прибавить к старому значению:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/вашпуть:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```