# Неправильная установка deb пакета

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, deb

Из проекта сгенерировал deb пакет. Содержимое его проверил - все работает корректно (исполняемые файлы - client и server). Но после установки не могу запустить

```
/usr/local/bin$ ./server 
./server: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlite_db.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Эту библиотеку есть в deb пакете, но не пойму почему не видит после установки. Может для нее какая отдельная логика должна быть?

Comment: а что пишет `ldd server`?

Comment: Куда пакет инсталит собранные либы?

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498189/178576), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приложение не может получить доступ к библиотеке libsqlite_db.so или ищет не по адресу расположения ( как правило это /urs/lib* ).

Соответственно создаём привязку при помощи ldconfig:

В файл */etc/ld.so.conf.d/{**имя_библиотеки**}.conf* или */etc/ld.so.conf* добавляем путь к библиотеке:

```
/путь/к/libsqlite_db.so
```

Далее выполняем от рута (sudo) `ldconfig -v` для обновления кэша.

Для проверки пути библиотеки в кэше `ldconfig -p | grep libsqlite`

Что бы узнать где приложение ищет библиотеку и находит ли вообще `ldd ./server`